# CSS3 first div only trick

Tags: css

I have a container with a bunch of divs. I want a top-border of grey on all of them except the first one should be top border of white. I tried nth-child but something seems wrong in my code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> Stuff </div>
  <div class="row"> Stuff </div>
  <div class="row"> Stuff </div>
  <div class="row"> Stuff </div>
</div>

.row{ border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: #ccc;}
.row:nth-child1{  border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: #FFF;}
```

Comment: It should be: `:nth-child(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.row { border-top: 1px solid #ccc;}
.row:first-child {  border-top-color: #FFF;}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MSDYY/

and another one, with background set to red, to show that there actually is white top border over first element: http://jsfiddle.net/MSDYY/1/

If you want to use `nth-child` it should look like this way: `.row:nth-child(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Either use:

```
.row:nth-child(1)
```

or

```
.row:first-of-type
```

or

```
.row:first-child
```

The top two are IE9+, but the last will work in IE8 as well.